# Unallocated Skill Points in Character Sheet in EVE?

Tags: eve-online

I have just logged into EVE Online for the first time after the latest patch and now on the character sheet of all of my characters I see the following;

[image]

I'm not seeing anything in the patch notes that would explain where these appeared from. Obviously to apply them I can just follow the instructions in the tooltip but what I would like to know is where did these unallocated skill points come from?

Comment: To those voting to close a Too Localised - the reason behind this may well fall into that category, but the mechanic for delivering skill points is not and there is nothing stopping CCP from using this method in the future.

Comment: Always read the Announcements and always read the DevBlogs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recent trouble with the new launcher meant that some pilots could not log into their accounts. To compensate for potentially lost skill time due to that, CCP has given every account 50.000 skill points.

[From the EVE forums:](https://forums.eveonline.com/default.aspx?g=posts&m=3078112#post3078112)

> With the deployment of Retribution 1.2.4 and the deployment of the new
>   launcher, we received reports internally and externally that people
>   were unable to connect to Tranquility thanks to some misconfigured
>   servers. While this issue was not universally experienced and over
>   30,000 pilots were able to log in normally before we fixed the issue,
>   we do feel this special case does require a special thank you (for
>   your patience) from CCP.
>
> During tomorrow's downtime we will add 50.000 skillpoints
>   (representing roughly a day’s worth of intense skill training) to the
>   character with the highest number of skill points on each active
>   account (the presumed main). Here’s a quick guide on how to apply
>   those skillpoints.

Comment: Moreover here is the procedure to spend them : http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Skill_Reimbursement